# How Does One "Consult" a Book on a Random Topic in Interactive Fiction?

Tags: inform7

I started with the [*Costa Rican Ornithology*](http://inform7.com/book/WI_7_6.html#e94) example, which works as expected.  I had the idea, largely for my own gratification, of allowing the player to flip randomly through the book since I don't expect to release this, to sample a random topic.

I pieced this together from several other examples.

```
Understand "consult [a book]" as consulting vaguely.

Consulting vaguely is an action applying to one visible thing.

Carry out consulting vaguely:
    let B be the book;
    let L be the number of rows in the contents of B;
    let N be a random number from 1 to L;
    choose row N in the contents of B;
    say "[reply entry][paragraph break]".
```

I've separated out the steps for clarity (and to ease the parsing and error reporting), but basically, choose a random row in the table of contents, then print the result.  I also tried `choose a random row...` but that doesn't change the results seen below.

Where `contents` (like in the example) represents the table of topics and results.

```
A book is a kind of thing.  A book has a table name called the contents.
```

Unfortunately, this code crashes the game when trying to "consult book," with the following run-time error.

> *** Run-time problem P10: Since the your former self is not allowed the
> property “contents”, it is against the rules to try to use it.

Ah-ha, I said to myself, `contents` sounds like what might sit inside a container, so of course I can't access it.  I can change it to something distinct like `ToC`, "table of contents," though the meaning is less important than it not colliding with another name.

Unfortunately, that also doesn't work, leading me to believe that `a table name` is not the same as a table.  This makes sense, but I don't see any path to *bridging* from the table's name (if that's actually what I'm seeing) to the actual table.  And I also don't know that I understand what my "former self" has to do with anything, but I don't know how critical that is in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you're referring to the book that the player has used in the command as "the book" but that's not correct – it should be "the noun". As "a book is a kind of thing" there is no "the book", you have to be more specific *which* book you mean. In this case it's "the noun" which is what the player specified in their command.

```
Carry out consulting vaguely:
    let B be the noun;
    let L be the number of rows in the contents of B;
    let N be a random number from 1 to L;
    choose row N in the contents of B;
    say "[reply entry][paragraph break]".
```

or more compactly,

```
Carry out consulting vaguely:
    choose a random row in the contents of the noun;
    say "[reply entry][paragraph break]".
```